# Why is firstChild.data returning Undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have following JavaScript code snippet which reads a dynamically created XML file by a php script and writes text accordingly in destination html page.

```
function process()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {

        var user = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
        var url = "http://localhost/dashboard/x/js/login.php?user="+user;
        xmlHttp.open("GET",url, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        //alert(user);
    }
    else
    {

        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}


function handleServerResponse()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4||xmlHttp.readyState==0)
    {
        if(xmlHttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            alert(xmlDocumentElement);      // [object element]
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            alert(message);                 // undefined
            document.getElementById("errorprompt").innerHTML = message;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

also the login.php file is as below-

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
echo '<root>';
    $user=$_GET['user'];
    $userArray=array("vishalkhare39@gmail.com","khare39vishal@rediffmail.com");
    if(in_array($user,$userArray))
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">;</a><strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>';
    else
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">;</a><strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>';
echo '</root>';
?>
```

My problem is that i am not able to print required message through `document.getElementById("errorprompt").innerHTML = message;`

I figure out that `alert(xmlDocumentElement);` is displaying `[object element]` and `alert(message)` is displaying `undefined`

Please let me know what should `alert(xmlDocumentElement)` print ideally?

also interestingly when i change the code of handleServerResponse() to following-

```
function handleServerResponse()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4||xmlHttp.readyState==0)
    {
        if(xmlHttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML;
            message=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0].textContent;
            document.getElementById("errorprompt").innerHTML = message;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

It is now printing the text contents of tag 'root' from XML. But now the problem is that it is not printing any markup code like `<div class="example">` etc. due to which styling is not what is desired.

Please help me out here. I am not able to find out any useful resource anywhere and had wasted a lot of hours in it.
Please give a solution so as to how can i set the message variable equal to complete response what php script is throwing.(including markups)

Comment: firstChild could be whitespace, and `.data` is not for elements.

Comment: Just replace `.data` with `.innerHTML` and you should get what you want.

Comment: Thank you @PetrSrníček
It worked.. :)